# Allegro padstack not showing my pads

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, layout, orcad, allegro

I have implemented a schematic for an IC (BGM13S32F512GA-V2R) and I am trying to create a footprint but when I try to place the padstacks, they do not appear in the default library... so I went into the settings and added a link to my directory with priority over the standard library. They are still not showing up.

[image: screenshot showing that the files are in the library folder]

Comment: cadance is crazy hard to use

Comment: F*** orcad used to be a frequent utterance from my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that allegro pcb editor does not search subfolders for .pad files, and in order for these to show up, they must all be at the root of the library. A bit less organized than I like, but what can ya do.

[image: picture showing pads displaying properly in menu]

Comment: i might have discovered this a while back to but i forget since it al happened in the span of about 5 minutes. i do remember needing to add a bunch of directories.